# SharePoint Migration from 2013 OnPrem to Online - advice seeked

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, migration, content-migration, sharepoint-permissions

Afternoon

I'm soon to begin migrating a onprem 2013 SharePoint site to online using the SharePoint migration tools. Looking for some general advice, dos and don'ts and any advice on migrating permissions.

Any advice welcome

Comment: I suggest running test migrations early in the process, you really won't know how your content will migrate over until you run a test.  After the test you will need some QA, possibly with end users / "Power Users", to find all your issues.  Then you can start addressing issues either on 2013, so the issue will not be one after the final migration, or if you can't address the issue in 2013 you will need to list out what steps you need to take post migration to correct them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are migrating from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint online. First have a look at the official tool SharePoint Migration Tool, The SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT) can migrate your files from SharePoint on-premises document libraries, lists or regular files shares.
Here is an overall [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/migrate-to-sharepoint-online) about it. Have a check on it and relevant articles.

Before migration, use the SharePoint Assessment Tool to assess and identify issues with SharePoint Server content prior to migration.
To download: [SharePoint Migration Assessment Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53598)  Ideal for assessing SharePoint Server 2010 and 2013 content prior to migration.

For permissions, here is some information if using SPMT:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/understanding-permissions-when-migrating

Here is a blog about an actual migration example which may be helpful,
https://andrewwarland.wordpress.com/2018/08/25/migrating-to-sharepoint-online-part-1-planning/